# Matching variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following code snippet should display an alert if `x` variable have text "I have right text right here" but my code does not work. Why?

```
var x = "Im the variable and I have right text right here";

if ("x:contains("I have right text right here").lenght > 0") {
  alert("Match")
}
```

Comment: Please look for string concatenation in javascript. You are missing a very small but very important thing there.

Comment: Also check the spelling of length in your code

Comment: And btw, you should learn how to debug js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Am I the only one who feels that the quality of this question very low and this should not get an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

```
var x = "Im the variable and I have right text right here";

if ( x.indexOf("I have right text right here")  > 0 ) {
  alert("Match")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
    var x = "Im the variable and I have right text right here";

    if ( x.includes("I have right text right here")) {
        alert("Match")
    }
```